# Proof that continuous functions that are equal almost everywhere are equal everywhere

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

I am trying to prove that for $f,g$ real valued and continuous functions: if $f=g$  a.e w.r.t $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure, then then they are equal everywhere.

I try the following: for $x\in \mathbb{R}$, pick a sequence $\{q_i\}$ of rationals such that $\{q_i\}\rightarrow x$. I claim that $$f(x)\neq g(x)$$ on a set of positive measure if $$ \cap_{i=0}\cup_{j\geq i}\{q_j: f(q_j)\neq g(q_j)\}$$ has positive measure. the rationale being that if I can always find a rational in the tail sequence such that they differ on this rational, then they can't be equal in the limit...

Now I use that $$\sum_{j} \lambda\left(\{q_j: f(q_j)\neq g(q_j)\}\right)<\infty$$ since they differ on set that have vanishing $\lambda$ measure, by the Borel Cantelli lemma we have then that $$\lambda\left(\cap_{i=0}\cup_{j\geq i}\{q_j: f(q_j)\neq g(q_j)\}\right)=0$$, so that $f(x)=g(x)$. Since $x$ was arbitrary then the functions are everywhere equal.

I would appreciate any pointers on potential mistakes so that I can fix it and learn that way, rather than "*just do it like that*", if possible :)

Answer (score 1):

You state that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $(q_j)\subset \mathbb{Q}$ with $q_j\to_j x$
$$
\emptyset\neq\cap_{i=0}\cup_{j\geq i}\{q_j: f(q_j)\neq g(q_j)\} \implies f(x)\neq g(x)
$$
Yet you show that
$$\lambda\left(\cap_{i=0}\cup_{j\geq i}\{q_j: f(q_j)\neq g(q_j)\}\right)=0 
$$
but this does not imply that $\cap_{i=0}\cup_{j\geq i}\{q_j: f(q_j)\neq g(q_j)\}=\emptyset$ and even if it did, the above statement wouldn't allow for the implication that $f(x)=g(x)$. Also Note that
$$
\cap_{i=0}\cup_{j\geq i}\{q_j: f(q_j)\neq g(q_j)\} \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^\infty\{q_i\} \subset \mathbb{Q}
$$
so monotonicity and that $\lambda(\mathbb{Q})=0$ also yields equality without Borel-Cantelli.

**Hints to how i would prove it:**

> Instead i would assume that $f(x)\not =g(x)$ for some $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Then use continuity of $f$ and $g$ (hence of $f-g$) to show that there exists an interval $I=(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ for some $\delta>0$, such that $f(y)\not = g(y)$ for all $y\in I$. Hereafter i would argue that this is a contradiction with $f=g$ $\lambda$-a.e.

Comment: I clarified what I meant with the empty set. Now regarding your comment: I would have thought that since it is true that "infinitely often" $f=g$ on a sequence of rationals converging to $x$, coupled with the fact that both functions are continuous would imply that $f=g$ in the limit. How is that argument faulty ?

Answer (score 1):

Why use the rationals?  The only nice thing about them is that they're *dense* in $\Bbb R$, and we have a better set to use for that.

**Sketch of Proof:** let $S$ be a set of measure zero such that $f = g$ on $\Bbb R \setminus S$.  Note that $S$ cannot contain any open intervals, and therefore has empty interior (justify this!).  Conclude that $\Bbb R \setminus S$ is *dense* in $\Bbb R$.  Conclude that since $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R \setminus S$, it must be by continuity that $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in \Bbb R$.