# Prob. 1, Chap. 3, in Royden's REAL ANALYSIS: If continuous functions $f$ and $g$ agree a.e. on $[a,b]$, then $f=g$ on $[a,b]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Here is Prob. 1, Chap. 3, in the book *Real Analysis* by H. L. Royden and P. M. Fitzpatrick, 4th edition:

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions on $[a, b]$. Show that if $f = g$ a.e. on $[a, b]$, then, in fact, $f = g$ on $[a, b]$. Is a similar assertion true if $[a, b]$ is replaced by a general measurable set?

My Attempt:

> Let $E_0$ be a subset of $[a, b]$ such that $m^* \left( E_0 \right) = 0$ and $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x \in [a, b] \setminus E_0$.

What next? How to proceed from here?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/543648/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1944857/42969

Comment: The set where two continuous functions agree is a closed set.

Comment: You still haven't made any comment to the detailed answer I have done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4154808) to one of your recent questions (I was the unique answerer). Consider that people who spend time to solve your questions desire to have some echo, at least some days later...

Comment: @JeanMarie I'm really sorry but earlier on I just couldn't examine your post carefully enough so as to be able to give any feedback.

Answer (score 3):

The set $[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ is measurable. Let $f(x) = x$ for $x$ in this set, and let $g(x)= x$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $g(2)=3.$ Then $f$ and $g$ agree almost everywhere on their domain, and both are continuous on that domain, but they don't agree everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E=\{x\in [a,b]:f(x)\ne g(x)\}$. Since $E$ has measure $0$, for each $x\in [a,b]$, there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $[a,b]\setminus E$ such that $x_n\to x$. (Why?)

Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous,
$$0 = \lim_{n\to\infty}[f(x_n)-g(x_n)] = f(x)-g(x).$$

Comment: can you please also answer the (Why?) in your post?

Comment: In order to find such a sequence, we have to show that, for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$, the set $(x-1/n, x+1/n) \cap [a,b]$ contains a point $x_n$ which doesn't lie in $E$. What would happen if that weren't the case for one $n\in \mathbb{N}$?