# What is the intuition behind creating the counter example?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to answer the second part in this question:

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are continuous functions on $[a,b].$ Show that if $f = g$ a.e. on $[a,b],$ then, in fact, $f = g$ on $[a,b].$ Is a similar assertion true if $[a,b]$ is replaced by a general measurable set $E$?

Here is a counter example I found here [Prob. 1, Chap. 3, in Royden's REAL ANALYSIS: If continuous functions $f$ and $g$ agree a.e. on $[a,b]$, then $f=g$ on $[a,b]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4164357/prob-1-chap-3-in-roydens-real-analysis-if-continuous-functions-f-and-g/4164366#4164366) :

The set $[0,1]\cup\{2\}$ is measurable. Let $f(x) = x$ for $x$ in this set, and let $g(x)= x$ for $x\in[0,1]$ and $g(2)=3.$ Then $f$ and $g$ agree almost everywhere on their domain, and both are continuous on that domain, but they don't agree everywhere.

**My question is:**

I know that the main idea that we used in the proof of the first part was "every nonempty open set in $E = [a,b]$ has positive measure", but I do not understand how by changing our $E$ to $[0,1] \cup \{2\}$ we broke this idea , could anyone explain this to me please?

Comment: One difference: $\{2\}$ is an open subset of $E$ of measure zero.

Comment: why it is an **open** subset of $E$ and not closed?@BrianO

Comment: The singleton is open with respect to subspace topology that $E$ inherits from the real line (because for example $\{2\}=(1,10) \cap E$ is an open subset of the real line intersected with $E$), but clearly the singleton has zero Lebesgue measure.

Comment: It's both open and closed. Open because it's an intersection of $E$ with an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$, for example $U = (3/2, 5/2)$. Thus, another difference: $E$ is disconnected, unlike any interval.

Comment: Also, you seem to be forgetting the important saying in topology "sets are not doors"

Comment: As far as I understand singletons are closed in $\mathbb R$ with respect to the standard topology on $\mathbb R.$ So why we needed the subspace topology in our example?@peek-a-boo

Comment: As far as I understand singletons are closed in $\mathbb R$ with respect to the standard topology on $\mathbb R.$ So why we needed the subspace topology in our example?@BrianO

Comment: The topology on $E$ *is* the standard topology, ... *on* $E$ :) Singletons are closed in $E$ too. It's a counterexample! – an example of a less nice domain for which the conclusion of the theorem fails.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I have never heard this statement (sets are not doors) before :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea used in the proof was that if $f = g$ a.e. on $[a, b]$, then they agree on a dense subset of $[a, b]$, and hence by continuity agree on $[a, b]$. With your example, $f$ and $g$ do not agree on a dense subset of $[0, 1] \cup \{2\}$ since not every open ball around $\{2\}$ contains a point at which $f$ and $g$ agree.